# how to add copied data to newly created column in my code

Tags: excel, vba

i have attached a code , how to add copied data to newly created column in my code

```
Sub copy_paste()

Dim wbCopy As Worksheet
Dim wbDist As Workbook

Set wbCopy = Workbooks("Property Report -February_2022.xlsx").Worksheets("ATB PIVOT WSP")
Set wbDist = Workbooks("P02 Week 4 Building Services Summary.xlsb")


    Dim rngUsernameHeader As Range
    Dim rngHeaders As Range

    Set rngHeaders = Range("9:9") 'Looks in entire first row.
    Set rngUsernameHeader = rngHeaders.Find(what:="Movement", After:=Cells(9, 9))

    rngUsernameHeader.EntireColumn.Insert
    rngUsernameHeader.Offset(0, -1).Value = "P03 Week 5"

wbCopy.Range("b5:h5").Copy
**'wbDist.Worksheets("Adelaide").rngUsernameHeader.Offset(0, -1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True**


End Sub
```

Comment: `rngUsernameHeader.Cells(1,1).Offset(1, -1).Paste` should do the trick, if I'm understanding your code well enough. If that isn't what you are looking for, please add details to your question.

Comment: It is unclear which workbook and worksheet `Set rngHeaders = Range("9:9")` and `Cells(9, 9)` refer to, Please do clarify. `rngUsernameHeader` can be used only on its own i.e. it is where it is, on the worksheet that was active when you set `rngHeaders`.